# Java classpath and package problems - referencing multiple jar files

Tags: java, package, classpath

I have a java class I'm trying to run that references various other jar files. It looks something like this:

```
 package com.myapp.test;

 import java.io.File;
 import com.myapp.ref;
 import com.myapp.stuff;
 import com.strangersapp.stuff;
 import com.strangersapp.morestuff;

 public class myTest {
    public static void main... 
    ...
 }
```

The com.myapp.* classes are in another jar file called myapp.jar. The strangersapp classes are in a strangersapp.jar. There are several other referenced classes in various jars. My whole directory structure looks like this:

```
 myapp.jar
 strangersapp.jar
 someother.jar
 yetanother.jar
 etc.jar
 com\myapp\test\myTest.java
```

My problem is trying to compile and run this. I try the obvious but this command does NOT work. It doesnt pickup all the jar files:

```
 javac -cp . com\myapp\test\myTest.java
 java -cp . com.myapp.test.myTest
```

This command also does not work:

```
 javac -cp ".;*.jar" com\myapp\test\myTest.java
```

However, these commands do work:

```
 javac -cp ".;myapp.jar;strangersapp.jar;someother.jar;yetanother.jar;etc.jar" com\myapp\test\mTest.java
 java -cp ".;myapp.jar;strangersapp.jar;someother.jar;yetanother.jar;etc.jar" com.myapp.test.mTest
```

Would anyone know why my first java run statement is not working?? I dont want to type all the jar names out in the classpath reference...

Answer (score 0):

If you use -cp you have to name all the jars you want to include. To avoid that just add them to your manifest and java will pick them up.

For javac i think you are supposed to use -classpath rather than -cp

Comment: Actually, that is not true in Java 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath?rq=1

Comment: @tieTYT Actually it *is* true, but you can do it with a wildcard.

Comment: I actually missed this feature. Anyway i think using using the manifest is a better approach as you can control what you include in your classpath.

Comment: @EJP If you're using a wildcard, you are not naming all the jars you want to include.  You're naming a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
javac -cp ".;*.jar" com\myapp\test\myTest.java
java -cp ".;*.jar" com.myapp.test.myTest
```

Comment: I thought that was the right command too and tried it but get an NoClassDefFoundError. I've also tried the following:
     javac -classpath ".;*.jar" com\myapp\test\myTest.java

That didnt work either... I'm using JDK 6 and also tried JDK 7